# JavaScript filter one array of objects using another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, compare

What is the best algorithm or way in comparing or cheking two different array of objects and return data if there is a match based on my problem below. I have an array of object which is on the picture below which is jobs which contains array of skills. And I have an array of skills which contains skills and i wanted to check if any of the skills from array of skills if it exist on jobs skills . And if any of the skills from array of skills exist in jobs then return jobs only which matched skills. I want that only jobs with matched skills from array of skills will be return. It will check if any item from array of skills exist in jobs and if even one or more exist then it will return jobs with match. Thank you.,

## jobs (array of objects that contains array of skills)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH7sT.png)

## skills (array of  skills)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD0sa.png)

## code in getting the job response

```
data.jobs_data(me, params, token).then(function (response) {
            me.record.is_searching = false
            if (response.status == "200") {
                me.records.jobs = response.data.data
                console.log("Jobs:", me.records.jobs)
                var count = response.data.count
                count = count + 1
                me.setKeyWords(me.filters)
                Pagination.init(me, count)
                $timeout(function () {
                    me.record.is_searching = false
                }, 400)

            }
        })
```

## jobs skills

```
  me.load_job_details = function (detail) {
           console.log("Skills :" , me.record.job_detail.skills)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```js
var skillObj = [
  "Python",
  "Photoshop",
  "Java Dev",
  "System Administrator",
  "Software Engineer"
];

var jobObj = [{
  "address": "address1",
  "company": "abc",
  "skills": ['Software Engineer', 'Human Resource']
},{
  "address": "address2",
  "company": "xyz",
  "skills": ['Python', 'Photoshop']
},{
  "address": "address3",
  "company": "alpha",
  "skills": ['Data Analyst', 'BA']
}];

var res = jobObj.filter(obj => {
 return skillObj.some(r=> obj.skills.indexOf(r) >= 0);
});

console.log(res);
```